# XAML Set a Resource Key by Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to Change the Style of a Grid dynamically. For that Purpose let's suppose I have 3 Textblocks with 3 Contents defined.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Block1" Text="key1" />
<TextBlock x:Name="Block2" Text="key2" />
<TextBlock x:Name="Block3" Text="key3" />
```

For each of the keys (1,2,3) there is a Style defined with the Name x:Key="key1".
Now i want something like this in my Grid:

```
<Grid Style="{DynamicResource {Binding ElementName=Block1, Path=Text}} />
```

Is this possible in Default XAML or do I have to find a Workaround?

Comment: Man, I just have no idea waht you are trying to acheive... A style defined for a textblock can only target a textblock and one defined for a grid can only target a Grid.

Comment: You dont even see the Styles, so why are you talking about the Types? There are 3 Styles defined for the Grid and i want to attach 1 of them by the Text of the Textblock.

Comment: @Febertson How about a Binding with a Converter that converts a key string to a Style (that is e.g. loaded from Resources)?

Comment: Well then, post every code that's relevant maybe !

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the Hint. That's what i meant by Workaround. My first idea was to find a direct way, but i guess the Converter will be needed. I thought that maybe someone here finds another way of achieving this.

Comment: @Bruno The Styles aren't relevant. It is just relevant that they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible in Default XAML or do I have to find a Workaround?

No, I am afraid you cannot use the `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` markup extension with "dynamic" values like this. The keys of the resources must be known at compile time.

Binding to a property and use a converter would be one way:

```
<Grid Style="{Binding ElementName=Block1, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource converter}}">
```

But I guess that's a workaround.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer and the Code Snippet. I will mark your answer as correct, because it looks right to me :)